# Select randomly 1 or 2 values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an array made entirely of numbers :

```
indexes: number[]=[0 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 9 , 11 , 13 , 15]
```

What I want to do, is to select randomly 1 or 2 values from this array, than having these values as indexes of another array, again randomly to assign a value equal to 2 or 4, to the variables from the selected indexes.

Comment: lookup documentation for Math.random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taking a look at [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) documentation you have a random int function:

> ## Getting a random integer between two values
>
> This example returns a random integer between the specified values. The value is no lower than min (or the next integer greater than min if min isn't an integer), and is less than (but not equal to) max.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
```

You just need to use it with your needs.

---

Get one or two numbers:

```
getRandomInt(1, 2);
```

Get a random position in the array:

```
getRandomInt(0, number.length - 1);
```

Add 2 or 4 in the position (same as first one but `* 2`):

```
getRandomInt(1, 2) * 2;
```